# Write more than one file in fileStream

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, filestream

I'm currently working on a weather app for my assignments. I will like to know if there is a way for me to write more than one item in the fileStream. Or do i need to make a new fileStream to access the other information.

This is my code which is writing in my towns.

```
var fileStream:FileStream  = new FileStream();

//write file
function writeFile(town:String):void{
fileStream.open(file,FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTFBytes("<root>\n\t<town>" + town + "</town>\n</root>"); 

fileStream.close();
}
```

Comment: just use FileMode.APPEND

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `FileMode.WRITE`, use `FileMode.APPEND`:

```
function writeFile(town:String):void{
    fileStream.open(file,FileMode.APPEND);
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes("<root>\n\t<town>" + town + "</town>\n</root>"); 
    fileStream.close();
}
```